# getting an runtime error of reference binding to null pointer of 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int>'

Tags: c++

I am solving Cheapest Flights Within K Stops on Leetcode and I am getting a Runtime error of

> runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type
> 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int,
> int>>>' (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer

Why this error is occurring?

My code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findCheapestPrice(int n, vector<vector<int>>& flights, int src, int dst, int K) {
        vector<vector<pair<int,int>>> graph; //(u->{v,wt})
        for(vector<int> x: flights){
            graph[x[0]].push_back({x[1],x[2]});
        }
        set<pair<int,pair<int,int>>> s; //{wt,{v,#hope}}
        vector<int> spt(n,0), dist(n,INT_MAX);
        dist[src] = 0;
        s.insert({0,{src,0}});
        while(!s.empty()){
            auto p = *(s.begin());
            int u = p.second.first;
            int d = p.first;
            int hope = p.second.second;
            s.erase(s.begin());
            spt[u]=1;
            if(u == dst && hope==K+1)
                return d;
            else if(hope<=K){
                for(pair<int,int> v: graph[u]){
                    if(!spt[v.first] && dist[v.first]>dist[u]+v.second){
                        dist[v.first] = dist[u]+v.second;
                        s.insert({dist[v.first],{v.first,hope+1}});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

can anyone please tell me how to create the above graph(which I created using vector) using list<> stl of c++.

Comment: `graph` is an empty vector, so `graph[x[0]]` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you tell me how can I make above graph using a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize the vector of pair like this: Here 10000 is the size of the vector.

```
vector<pair<int, int>> graph (10000,make_pair(0, 0));
```